# Infinite while loop using conditional statements and peekable iterables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, iterator, more-itertools

I'm getting an infinite loop while using more_itertools peekable:

```
import more_itertools as it

temp = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('sample.txt')]
lines = it.peekable(temp)

try:
    while True:
        line = lines.next()
        if DESCRIPTION in line:
            description = line[len(DESCRIPTION) + 1:]
            sample = lines.peek()
            if CODE in sample:
                pass
            else:
                continue

        if(EOF in line):
            break


except StopIteration:
    pass
```

It gets caught in when I check if CODE is in sample, as it keeps looping through there. 
Where are things getting caught up? Thanks!

Comment: You're not getting an infinite loop because of using `peekable`. You are getting an infinite loop because you are never ending your infinite loop. You should issue a `break` in your while loop when it matches a break condition that you need it to break on. And Your code is not right...you have an `elif` with no matching `if`.

Comment: It's just a snippet. I've edited the question to match the actual structure.

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop instead of `for line in lines:` in the first place?

Comment: There is another condition later on that requires me to iterate indefinitely through.

Comment: @idjaw quick print debugging shows it gets stuck looping through in the if DESCRIPTION in line conditional statement.

Comment: @ahagouel Yes, as expected, because your `EOF in line` condition is never met. What exactly is your definition of `EOF` here? Did you check to see if `line` even has the `EOF` you are looking for?